# Liquibase ObjectQuotingStrategy with generateChangeLog with MariaDb

Tags: enums, liquibase

While using MariaDb, and running a generateChangeLog, It generates the changelog, but I get issues like:

```
<column name="status" type="ENUM(8)">
```

instead of

```
<column name="status" type="ENUM('enabled', 'disabled')">
```

presumably this is due to the quoting strategy being used while generating the changelog - how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from looking at the source code that the code to dig out the different enum values only runs if the database is an instanceof MySqlDatabase (see [ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java line 258](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/snapshot/jvm/ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java#L258)). I don't know how MariaDb is supported - if it is a subclass of MySqlDatabase then that would explain the problem.